# Simple Add Subtract with vibrations

Tags: java, android

Here is my code for a add and subtraction program but the question is what is the best way to incoporate vibrations on the phone so for example the text layout shows -1 for a number.. So the phone then vibrates a certain way for -1.. I know I need to do a if statement, but I seem to be having trouble.. Here is the java code for the program.. And thank you for the help!

```
package com.example.untitled3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add , sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Adds 1 to the counter
                counter = counter + 1;
                display.setText(" Your total is :" + counter);
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Subtract 1 from counter
                counter = counter - 1;
                display.setText(" Your total is :" + counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh, what does the code has in common with your question?

Comment: You don't have anything vibration related in your code. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your phone vibrate using the following code:

```
Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
```

On some condition(In your case, when the text shows -1) call this:

```
vibe.vibrate(200); // 200 is time in ms
```

And don't forget you need to add the permission to the manifest (after the `</application>` tag):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**EDIT:**

Create an integer variable initialized to zero. Increment the variable on clicking the add button and decrement it on clicking the subtract button. Every time after the click check the value of the count variable, if it is zero then call the `vibe.vibrate(200);`.

Comment: To clear the confusion I just want to know how to incorporate a if statement to start the vibration if the textfield shows -1.. I did the following updates as explained above

Comment: like so?                 if (counter == "-1") {
                vibr.vibrate(200);
            }

Comment: for comparing int variable write `if(counter == -1)` not `if(counter == "-1")`